# Loading config files in emacs

Tags: emacs

I have several config files in `~.emacs.d/elisp/`. I want to load them on emacs startup. I'm using this line:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elisp/")
```

I assume that adds the contents of the directory to the files loaded at startup. But the files are not loaded. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

emacs doesn't load automatically. you should explicitly ask emacs to load a file.

eg: to load a `feature.el` in `~/.emacs.d/elisp` directory
you can say..

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elisp/")
(require 'feature)
```

Comment: And if it is just a config file (not an emacs extension/package providing a feature), you may need `(load-file "~/.emacs.d/elisp/mysettings")`. require will work anyway (see the doc for require), but just as a fallback mechanism.